# Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have problem that I updated from elasticsearch 2.x to 5.1. However, some of my data does not work in newer elasticsearch because of this "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/fielddata.html before 2.x it was enabled it seems.

Is there way to enable fielddata automatically to text fields?

I tried code like this

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_template/template_1 -d '
{
  "template": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "properties": {
        "fielddata-*": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

but it looks like elasticsearch does not understand wildcard there in field name. Temporary solution to this is that I am running python script every 30 minutes, scanning all indices and adding fielddata=true to fields which are new.

The problem is that I have string data like "this is cool" in elasticsearch.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/example/exampleworking/1' -d '
{
    "myfield": "this is cool"
}'
```

when trying to aggregate that:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/example/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "aggs": {
        "foobar": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "myfield"
            }
        }
    }   
}'
```

"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [myfield]"

that elasticsearch documentation suggest using .keyword instead of adding fielddata. However, that is not returning data what I want.

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/example/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "aggs": {
        "foobar": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "myfield.keyword"
            }
        }
    }   
}'
```

returns:

```
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "this is cool",
      "doc_count" : 1
    }
  ]
```

which is not correct. Then I add fielddata true and everything works:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/example/_mapping/exampleworking' -d '
{
  "properties": {
        "myfield": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true
        }
    }
}'
```

and then aggregate

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/example/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "aggs": {
        "foobar": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "myfield"
            }
        }
    }   
}'
```

return correct result

```
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "cool",
      "doc_count" : 1
    },
    {
      "key" : "is",
      "doc_count" : 1
    },
    {
      "key" : "this",
      "doc_count" : 1
    }
  ]
```

How I can add this fielddata=true automatically to all indices to all text fields? Is that even possible? In elasticsearch 2.x this is working out of the box.

Comment: i will answer to myself

Answer (score 2):

i will answer to myself

```
curl -XPUT http:/localhost:9200/_template/template_1 -d '
{
  "template": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings2": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "text",
              "fielddata": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

this is doing what i want. Now all indexes have default settings fielddata true

Comment: Hi, I met the issue too. I applied your template and then do reindex, but still got error from kibana which draw a table by aggregate some text field. Are the correct steps: create template -> reindex an existing index and all text fields would be have "fielddata = true" ?

Comment: Adding `"fielddata": true` allows the text field to be aggregated, but this has performance problems at scale. A better solution is to add a second field to use a multi-field mapping. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding "fielddata": true allows the text field to be aggregated, but this has performance problems at scale. A better solution is to use a multi-field mapping.

Unfortunately, this is hidden a bit deep in Elasticsearch's documentations, in a warning under the fielddata mapping parameter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#before-enabling-fielddata

Here's a complete example of how this helps with a terms aggregation, tested on Elasticsearch 7.12 as of 2021-04-24:

Mapping (in ES7, under the `mappings` property of the body of a "put index template" request etc):

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "bio": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Four documents indexed:

```json
{
    "bio": "Dogs are the best pet."
}
```

```json
{
    "bio": "Cats are cute."
}
```

```json
{
    "bio": "Cats are cute."
}
```

```json
{
    "bio": "Cats are the greatest."
}
```

Aggregation query:

```json
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "bios_with_cats": {
            "filter": {
                "match": {
                    "bio": "cats"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "bios": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "bio.keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aggregation query results:

```json
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "bios_with_cats": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "bios": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Cats are cute.",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "Cats are the greatest.",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, this aggregation says "Of the documents whose bios are like 'cats', how many of each distinct bio are there?" The one document without "cats" in its `bio` property is excluded, and then the remaining documents are grouped into buckets, one of which has one document and the other has two documents.